# How do I query for objects that have a specific userid in firebase

Tags: ios, swift, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I have a firebase object called Calculations. Each object has a UserId so that I can later of the calculations created by a user. I can't seem to get the query to work and I'm not sure what I'm doing wrong.

```
let calculationsDB = Database.database().reference().child("Calculations").queryEqual(toValue: Auth.auth().currentUser!.uid, childKey: "UserId")

    //.child("UserId").queryEqual(toValue: Auth.auth().currentUser!.uid)
calculationsDB.observe(.childAdded) { (snapshot) in
    let snapshotValue = snapshot.value as! Dictionary<String, Any>
    self.stocksArray.append(Calculation(calDictionary: snapshotValue))
    self.configurTableView()
    self.mainTableView.reloadData()

}
```

Answer (score 2):

You should use `queryOrdered` before `queryEqual` to specify the property you're querying on:

```
let calculationsDB = Database.database().reference().child("Calculations").queryOrdered(byChild: "UserId").queryEqual(toValue: Auth.auth().currentUser!.uid)
```

Comment: Great answer Rosário! I closed the question against a dupe, but this is definitely the solution.